# How to get Docker container stdout in Jenkins logs?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

(Moved this question from Stack Overflow after getting no traction there; perhaps I'll have more luck here by getting consideration by more DevOps-specific experts)

As part of my Jenkins pipeline, I run a Docker container with Jenkins' `docker.withRun()`.
For the purpose of demonstration, the Docker container entrypoint is a trivial bash script that echoes an environment variable:

```
#! /bin/bash
# runme

if [ -z "$STR" ]
then
  echo 'STR is undefined'
else
  echo "STR is $STR"
fi
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM debian:10.3 as base

COPY ./runme /usr/local/bin

ENTRYPOINT runme
```

Building and running locally:

```
$ docker build --no-cache -t tmp .
[+] Building 0.3s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 109B                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:10.3                                0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/debian:10.3                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 26B                                                              0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY ./runme /usr/local/bin                                                         0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f5b6fdb3035c12a061c1221f570f126f5a7479e7e3ab07bba0a9694b5b04ab52  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/tmp                                                        0.0s
$ docker run -t tmp
STR is undefined
$ docker run -e STR=foo -t tmp
STR is foo
$
```

I try to run this same Docker container from a Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  options { timestamps{} }

  stages {
    stage('docker run') {
      steps {
        script {
          def img = 'tmp'
          def docker_run_args = '-t -e STR=foo'
          def ms = docker.image(img)

          ms.withRun(docker_run_args) {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...I can see from the Jenkins job's console logs that the container is running, but its stdout is not included in the console logs:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (docker run)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
09:49:40  + docker run -d -t -e STAGE=foo tmp
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
09:49:45  + docker stop e5020f0e5416f34221d3cbc275fa44ccc05f9af03b138e4ec67d47b1d90a2d3a
09:49:45  e5020f0e5416f34221d3cbc275fa44ccc05f9af03b138e4ec67d47b1d90a2d3a
09:49:45  + docker rm -f e5020f0e5416f34221d3cbc275fa44ccc05f9af03b138e4ec67d47b1d90a2d3a
09:49:45  e5020f0e5416f34221d3cbc275fa44ccc05f9af03b138e4ec67d47b1d90a2d3a
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

As you can see from the above, the string "`STR is ...`" is not included in the Jenkins job's console logs, but appears in my terminal's stdout just fine when I run the container myself.
I tried using `docker.run()` instead of `docker.withRun()`, but it didn't change the behavior.

**Is there a way I can get the Docker container's stdout included in the Jenkins job's console logs?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to run that docker in interactive mode.

```
docker run --rm -it -e STR=foo tmp
```

- `-i` - interactive mode
- `--rm` - to delete the container once finished the process (`tmp`)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Docker stdout into a variable as follows and then log it at will.

```
script {
  myVar = sh(script: 'docker run -e STR=foo -t tmp', returnStdout: true).trim() 
  println "got ${myVar}"
}
```